# Check if one or both input fields are empty, have 0 as value or a negative number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two input fields that look like this:

```
<input type="number" class="formateninput form-control hoogtebreedte" name="breedte" max="<?php echo $explodemax[0]?>" min="<?php echo $explodemin[0]?>">
<input type="number" class="formateninput form-control hoogtebreedte" name="hoogte" max="<?php echo $explodemax[1]?>" min="<?php echo $explodemin[1]?>">
```

I don't want for people to be able to enter a value of 0, less then 1 or nothing before continuing.

So in my jquery I have the following if statement:

```
if($('.hoogtebreedte').val() !== '' && $('.hoogtebreedte').val() !== 0 && $('.hoogtebreedte').val() > 0){
go ahead
}else{
stop
}
```

Everything works except when you add a number, for example 90 to the first input, and 0 to the second, it still proceeds. Why is that, how can I fix it?

Comment: so from your question basically if you enter a value in first input box as 5 the second input box should take values from 5 to n, not less than 5

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS No both input fields must never contain 0, be less than 0 or be empty.

Comment: You are only checking the first one with that `if()`. Also, the `!==0` won't work since values are strings

Comment: @charlietfl But they both have the same classes right

Comment: Yes but `$('.hoogtebreedte').val()` can only return a single value.....and it will be from first matching element

Comment: @charlietfl So is it possible to check for both with one if statement? Or do I need to add a different class for both input fields?

Comment: Consider using an  `each` loop or `filter()` to check all of them. Then you test each instance separately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were checking only first value of `.hoogtebreedte` class so the second value was not check.

Below is working example:

```js
function test () {
  if($('.hoogtebreedte').eq(0).val() !== '' && $('.hoogtebreedte').eq(0).val() > 0 &&   $('.hoogtebreedte').eq(1).val() !== '' && $('.hoogtebreedte').eq(1).val() > 0){
    console.log('everything is ok')
  } else  {
    console.log('something is wrong')
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="formateninput form-control hoogtebreedte" name="breedte" max="99" min="0">
<input type="number" class="formateninput form-control hoogtebreedte" name="hoogte" max="99" min="0">
<button onclick='test()'>test</button>
```

In addition, for multiple class you can use this code:

```js
function validate () {
  const validate = Array.from($('.hoogtebreedte')).every((_,index) => $('.hoogtebreedte').eq(index).val() !== '' && $('.hoogtebreedte').eq(index).val() > 0)
  return validate ? console.log('everything is ok') : console.log('something is wrong')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="formateninput form-control hoogtebreedte" name="breedte" max="99" min="0">
<input type="number" class="formateninput form-control hoogtebreedte" name="hoogte" max="99" min="0">
<input type="number" class="formateninput form-control hoogtebreedte" name="hoogte" max="99" min="0">
<button onclick='validate()'>validate</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse the value of your input as an integer before doing your validations, since the value of an input element is always a string.

**Working example:**

```js
const check = () => {
  let a = parseInt(document.getElementById("a").value)
  let b = parseInt(document.getElementById("b").value)
  
  if(a >= 1 && b >= 2) {
    alert("Everything is good!")
  } else {
    alert("Either 'a' or 'b' are less than 1 or empty.")
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="a">
<input type="number" id="b">

<button id="check" onclick="check()">Check</button>
```

**Note:** I'm not checking for value equal to the empty string, since parseFloat will return NaN (Not a Number) for a value that can't be parsed as an integer and NaN >= 1 is always false.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="number" id="breedte" class="formateninput form-control hoogtebreedte" name="breedte">
<input type="number" id="hoogte" class="formateninput form-control hoogtebreedte" name="hoogte">
<input id="btnSubmit" type="button" value="Submit" />

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
        var input1 = parseInt($('#breedte').val());
        var input2 = parseInt($('#hoogte').val());
        if (input1 > 0 && input2 > 0) {
            alert('Go ahead');
        } else {
            alert('Stop!!!');
        }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happing just because you are taking value from `class`  in jQuery it treat as an array.

so you in logically you are second input is not getting validate.

`each` will solve your problem.

```
$('.validate').on('click',function(){
    var status = false;
    $('.hoogtebreedte').each(function(){
        var t = $(this);
        if(t.val() === '' || t.val() == 0 || t.val() < 0){
            status = true
        }
    })
    if(status) {
        console.log('stop')
    } else {
        console.log('go')
    }

})
```

[Working Code here](https://codepen.io/onlinegurucool/pen/KKKopQQ)

Answer (score 1):

Add `on('input')` event in order to check the condition every time you introduce a number and make the function 'generic' to work on any input. If the inserted value is 0 or 1, make input red

```js
function validateInput(myInput) {
  $('#' + myInput).on('input', function(evt) {
    var value = evt.target.value
    console.log(value)

    if (value === '0' || value === '1') {
      evt.target.className = 'invalid'
    } else {
      evt.target.className = 'valid'
    }
  })
}

validateInput('first')
validateInput('second')
```

```css
input.valid {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

input.invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="first" class="formateninput form-control hoogtebreedte" name="breedte" max="<?php echo $explodemax[0]?>" min="<?php echo $explodemin[0]?>">
<input type="number" id="second" class="formateninput form-control hoogtebreedte" name="hoogte" max="<?php echo $explodemax[1]?>" min="<?php echo $explodemin[1]?>">
```